NGINX cannot resolve docker container service
I have a Linux server with NGINX where I deploy docker-compose projects.
On the server I'm running docker compose with a service exposed on port 12345 (an example).
docker-compose.yml:
name: poc-docker

  services:
    api:
      container_name: api
      #hostname: api
      image: ...
      expose: [12345]
      networks: [poc-one]

  networks:
    poc-one:
      driver: bridge

NGINX conf (service location):
    location / {
        #proxy_pass http://localhost:12345;  OK when add port mapping 12345:12345
        #proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:50200; OK when pick internal IP inspecting container
        # I don't want this simple "api" because other project can use the same name
        #proxy_pass http://api:12345;  

        # ALL these fails:
        proxy_pass http://poc-docker_poc-one_api:12345;
        proxy_pass http://poc-one_api:12345;
        proxy_pass http://poc-docker_api:12345;
    }

What the hell should be the container alias?
I believe the moist precise should be {project name}{network}{service name}:{port} but it doesn't work.
With IP it works, so service is exposed on that port.
I don't want another NGINX instance in every project I add to the server.
My idea is to have a single NGINX running on the server where I add specific configuration when I add a new docker-compose to the server.

I used a ports mapping with the localhost IP and it seems to make the container reachable from the local server but not public.
ports:
 - 127.0.0.1:12345:12345

In NGINX I can use both 127.0.0.1 or localhost.
